# как обрезать готовые график в matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

у меня есть график который я строю:

```
x1.pcolormesh(average_data_windward, cmap='jet', shading='gouraud', vmin=minnim, vmax=maxxim)
x1.contour(average_data_windward, linewidths=0.5, colors='black', linestyles='-')
```

как мне обрезать его по синим границам, чтобы область заштрихованная синей линией ушла, и система отсчета началась заново от фиолетовой точки(т.е. это точка было (0,0)
Мне нужно именно обрезать, я не могу сразу построить нужные мне график(потому что так устроена pcolormesh)

Comment: `xlim` и `ylim` пробовали устанавливать?

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо большое! set_xlim помогло тк я использую subplots